# How to open strongly type view into popup control by calling action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I have parent page which contain gridview. When I right click on any row from grid view context menu will get open. By selecting context menu I want to open popup with strongly type view. I have open popup with strongly type view.
    But problem is that I have to create data member into parent view model to pass model object to popup view. I don't want that I want to call perticular action to open a view into popup. because one parent view can open multiple popup so for all popup I have to create one data member in parent view model.
e.g.
  I want to open send product information popup by selecting customer record from grid.

Controller

```
  public class ProductController : Controller
    {
      public ViewResult SendProductInformation()
        {
            ProductModel objProductModel  = new ProductModel ();
            return View(objProductModel  );
        }
   [HttpPost] 
      public ViewResult SendProductInformation()
        {
            ProductModel objProductModel  = new ProductModel ();
            return View(objProductModel  );
        }
}
```

View

```
@model UI.Areas.Product.ModelsProductModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product ";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>EmployeeModel</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

From parent view I am going to open popup controal following is popup controal

```
@Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "pcSendProductInformation";
        settings.Width = 1000;
        settings.Height = 350;
        settings.HeaderText = "Send Product Information";
        settings.Styles.Header.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Center;
        settings.Styles.Header.VerticalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.VerticalAlign.Middle;
        settings.Styles.Header.Font.Size = 10;
        settings.Modal = true;
        settings.ShowHeader = true;
        settings.ShowCloseButton = true;
        settings.CloseAction = DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CloseAction.CloseButton;
        settings.Left = 1245;
        settings.Top = 300;
        settings.Styles.ModalBackground.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        settings.SetContent(() =>
            Html.RenderAction("SendProductInformation","Product")
            );
    }).GetHtml()
```

But popup controal is giving error for Html.RenderAction("SendProductInformation","Product") when I use Html.RenderAction("SendProductInformationl", Model.productInfo) it will work
But I have to pass model object.

```
 Please give me solution to open popup with strongly type view by calling SendProductInformation action method .
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because "Product" passed to the controller as a parameter. Try something like this `Html.RenderAction(actionName: "action", controllerName: "controller")`

Comment: When I use Html.RenderAction(actionName: "action", controllerName: "controller")  code, action method get called at the time of loading parent page, & in firefox I got following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: MVCxClientNavBar is not defined"

Comment: It's a javascript error? If so, can you provide the stacktrace of this error from the firebug? At the same time, try to check where do you call DevExpress client side API.